# Como añado un argumento de la linea de comando al compilar una solucion de C++ usando Jenkins?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, shell, jenkins

Antes de nada llevo dos semanas probando Jenkins para aprender con el a traves de tutoriales y stackoverflow, por lo que tengo muy poca experiencia.
Tengo una solucion de C++ que incluye 10 proyectos, uno de ellos necesita pasar un "command argument" para compilarlo, cuando lo hacia manualmente simplemente hacia `click derecho en el projecto -> properties -> Debugging -> Command arguments`. Mi problema es que no se como extrapolar esto a un pipeline de jenkins, pues añadiendo cualquier tipo de argumento en el paso de building, entiendo que ese argumento es para la solucion entera y no para el projecto especifico que quiero pasarle ese argumento. Esto es posible de hacer en un pipeline usando MS Build para compilar?. Este es el step de compilado de mi pipeline de momento:

```
        stage('Build'){
            steps{
                script {
                    def msbuild = tool name: 'MSBuild', type: 'hudson.plugins.msbuild.MsBuildInstallation'
                    bat "\"${msbuild}\" C:/Users/User/.jenkins/workspace/project/Source/project.sln"
                } 
            }
```

Cualquier ayuda o consejo es bien recibida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins dispone de un plugin llamado [MSBuild](https://plugins.jenkins.io/msbuild/) que sirve, justamente, para proporcionar una interfaz que permita compilar proyectos de Visual Studio. Lamentablemente, el plugin aún [no es compatible](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) con el modo pipeline.

No obstante, no hay que olvidar que el plugin no es más que un azucarillo que sirve para simplificar un proceso, es decir, no hace magia. Si MSBuild permite pasar parámetros a la compilación es porque tiene algun parámetro que nos permite justamente eso. Es decir, basta con revisar la [interfaz de MSBuild](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019).

Seguramente debas utilizar el parámetro `-property`:

```
-property:Parametro1=Valor1;Parametro2=Valor2;...
```

Con lo que tu pipeline quedaría así:

```
bat "MSBuild.exe -property:Parametro=Valor C:/Users/User/.jenkins/workspace/project/Source/project.sln"
```

En cualquier caso, no es recomendable usar rutas absolutas en jenkins, ya que si cambias el nombre del job o la configuración del agente, el directorio de trabajo cambiará y tu job fallará sin remedio.

Un *job* de jenkins tiene como directorio de trabajo la carpeta específica de dicho *job*, es decir, si estás compilando el *job* "project", y el *workspace* del agente es `C:/Users/User/.jenkins`, el directorio de trabajo del *job* será `C:/Users/User/.jenkins/workspace/project`, con lo que podríamos simplificar y mejorar el script facilmente:

```
bat "MSBuild.exe -property:Parametro=Valor Source/project.sln"
```

Comment: Genial muchas gracias!

Comment: por cierto MSBuild si que sirve en pipelines perfectamente

Comment: @jesusfernandez no es un plugin que haya probado... me ciño a lo que dice la documentación